# Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'rowguid'

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I have a C# script in my SSIS package which manipulates two CSV files and writes another CSV file. The data from the new CSV files goes through a lookup match and is then updated in the SQL Server databases.

The CSV files do not have the "rowguid" column, and my understanding was that SQL server generates the rowguid values by itself. So, in the column mapping in the OLEDB destination, nothing is mapped to the rowguid variable.

On executing the package, I get the following error on the ODB DashboardStats component, which maps the error output to the database table:
"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'rowguid'

I looked at similar posts but I do not want to make the rowguid column in the database nullable since it's not the best practice.I have also tried un-checking Keep Identity in ODB DashboardStats, shown in the diagram below, but that didn't help either.
In this case, would the best bet me to insert a rowguid column through SSIS?If so, what would be the best way to do that?(C#, SSIS newbie :( )

Below are some screenshots for reference:
  [image]

[image]

Comment: It depends on the underlying structure of the table, but my GUESS is that the table is keyed off of rowguid , or rowguid may simply just not be allowed to be null. I think perhaps your assumption is faulty that it automatically generates them. If the table has a default set up on that column for say `newid()` then it should automatically generate it. If it doesnt however, you'll have to either alter the table to have it, or create a derived column in your SSIS package to generate a guid for the column. You can run `sp_help <myTable>` to see constraints on the table.

Answer (score 0):

In the database table itself, a uniqueidentifier constraint can be put on rowguid, which auto generates the data and eliminates the error.An example would go like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableName] ADD  CONSTRAINT [MSmerge_df_rowguid_AA7400445B994489BB04D2C090DB574C]  DEFAULT (NEWSEQUENTIALID()) FOR [rowguid]
GO
```